# Load html page content(require jquery scripting support) into a div using ajax/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I am a new user here, I want to inform you all that i had thoroughly searched regarding my problem but the solution i found doesn't work perfectly.

Here is my code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org  /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>R A</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/stylesheet.css"
  />
   <script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="script/accord.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery.nivo.slider.js"></script>
   <script>
 $(window).load(function() {
    $('#slider').nivoSlider({
        effect: 'random',
        directionNavHide: false,
        pauseOnHover: true,
        captionOpacity: 1,
        prevText: '<',
        nextText: '>'
    });
});
   </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script/loadcontent.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body>

 <div id="wrapper">
 <div id="header">
    <img class="headright" src="images/leaf-Rt.gif" width="48" height="50" alt="#">
    <img class="headright" src="images/pine-cone-Rt.gif" width="58"       
    height="50"           alt="#">
    <img class="headleft" src="images/leaf-Lt.gif" width="48" height="50" alt="#">
    <img class="headleft" src="images/pine-cone-Lt.gif" width="58" height="50" alt="#">
    <h1><i>R F I</i></h1>
    <h2><i>XYZ</i></h2>
</div>


   <ul id="menu">
<li><a id="link1" href"#">Home</a></li>
<li>
    <a href="#">Products</a>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Agarbatti</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href='#'>Raw</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Scented</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Flora</a></li>
            </ul>               
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Dhoop</a>
            <ul>
                 <li><a href='#'>Soft / Wet</a></li>
                 <li><a href='#'>Sticks</a></li>
                 <li><a href='#'>Cone</a></li>
                 <li><a href='#'>Sambrani</a></li>
            </ul>               
        </li>


   <li>
            <a href='#'>Loban</a>
  <ul>
     <li><a href='#'>Powder</a></li>
     <li><a href='#'>Hard</a></li>
   </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href='#'>Candles</a>
    <ul>
     <li><a href='#'>Rose Candles</a></li>
     <li><a href='#'>Decorative Candles</a></li>
     <li><a href='#'>Royal Candles</a></li>
     <li><a href='#'>Heart Candles</a></li>
     <li><a href='#'>Orchid Candles</a></li>
     <li><a href='#'>Floating Candles</a></li>
     <li><a href='#'>Ball Candles</a></li>
     <li><a href='#'>Christmas Candles</a></li>
     <li><a href='#'>Pillar Candles</a></li>
     <li><a href='#'>Gourmet Candles</a></li> 
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li ><a href='#'>Stands</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href='#'>Agarbatti / Incense</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>Loban Stands</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>Dhoops Stands</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>Candle Stands</a></li>
     </ul>
  </li>
  <li ><a href='#'>Puja Items</a>
  <ul>
     <li><a href='#'>Camphor</a></li>
     <li><a href='#'>Cow's Ghee</a></li>
     <li><a href='#'>Rumal/Chundari</a></li>
     <li><a href='#'>Mukut</a></li>
     <li><a href='#'>Mala</a></li>
     <li><a href='#'>Hawan Samagri</a></li>
     <li><a href='#'>Cotton</a></li>
     <li><a href='#'>Janva</a></li>
     <li><a href='#'>Gau Mutr</a></li> 
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li ><a href='#'>Mehndi</a></li>
  <li ><a href='#'>Napthelene Balls</a></li>
  <li ><a href='#'>Perfumes & Attars</a></li>        
  </ul>

  </li>
<li><a href="#">Testimonials</a></li>

<li>
    <a href="#">About</a>   
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#">Contact</a> 
</li>
   <li>
    <a href="#">Trade Enquiry</a>   
</li>
  </ul>


    <div id="outer">
    <div class="inner">            
    <div id="main" align="center">


    </div><!--end main-->
    <div id="left">

    <div id='cssmenu' style="top:2px">
    <ul>
    <li class='active'><a href='index.html'><span>Home</span></a></li>
    <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Incense Sticks</span></a>
    <ul>
     <li><a href='#'><span>Raw</span></a></li>
     <li><a href='#'><span>Scented</span></a></li>
     <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Flora</span></a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Dhoop</span></a>
    <ul>
     <li><a href='#'><span>Soft / Wet</span></a></li>
     <li><a href='#'><span>Sticks</span></a></li>
     <li><a href='#'><span>Cone</span></a></li>
     <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sambrani</span></a></li>
    </ul>
     </li>
    <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Loban</span></a>
    <ul>
     <li><a href='#'><span>Powder</span></a></li>
     <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Hard</span></a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Candles</span></a>
    <ul>
     <li><a href='#'><span>Rose Candles</span></a></li>
     <li><a href='#'><span>Decorative Candles</span></a></li>
     <li><a href='#'><span>Royal Candles</span></a></li>
     <li><a href='#'><span>Heart Candles</span></a></li>
     <li><a href='#'><span>Orchid Candles</span></a></li>
     <li><a href='#'><span>Floating Candles</span></a></li>
     <li><a href='#'><span>Ball Candles</span></a></li>
     <li><a href='#'><span>Christmas Candles</span></a></li>
     <li><a href='#'><span>Pillar Candles</span></a></li>
     <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Gourmet Candles</span></a></li> 
     </ul>
     </li>
     <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Stands</span></a>
     <ul>
     <li><a href='#'><span>Agarbatti / Incense</span></a></li>
     <li><a href='#'><span>Loban Stands</span></a></li>
     <li><a href='#'><span>Dhoops Stands</span></a></li>
     <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Candle Stands</span></a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Puja Items</span></a>
    <ul>
     <li><a href='#'><span>Camphor</span></a></li>
     <li><a href='#'><span>Cow's Ghee</span></a></li>
     <li><a href='#'><span>Rumal/Chundari</span></a></li>
     <li><a href='#'><span>Mukut</span></a></li>
     <li><a href='#'><span>Mala</span></a></li>
     <li><a href='#'><span>Hawan Samagri</span></a></li>
     <li><a href='#'><span>Cotton</span></a></li>
     <li><a href='#'><span>Janva</span></a></li>
     <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Gau Mutr</span></a></li> 
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Mehndi</span></a></li>
    <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Napthelene Balls</span></a></li>
    <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Air Freshner</span></a></li>
    <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Perfumes & Attars</span></a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>

    </div><!--end left-->
    <div class="clearer"></div>
    </div><!--end inner-->


    <div class="clearer"></div>

    </div><!--end outer-->

    <div id="footer" >
    <!-- <div class="iconleft">
        <a href="http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=referer"><img src="images/html-
     blue.png" alt="Valid HTML 4.01 Strict" height="31" width="88"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="iconright">
        <a href="http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/"><img src="images/css-blue.png" 
     alt="Valid CSS!" height="31" width="88"></a>
    </div>-->
    <p style="text-align:center;color:#FFF"> Copyright &#169;2013</p>  
    </div><!--end footer-->

    </div><!--end wrapper-->

   <div id="bodyfooter"></div>
   </div>

   </body>
   </html>
```

Now what I want to do here is that when i click my menu for home with id "#link1" the div of my main page i.e "#main" should load with en external html file home.html

home.html

```
    <br /><br />
       <div class="slider-wrapper futurico-theme" >

    <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">

        <img src="image/slideshow/cycleall.jpg" alt="">

        <img src="image/slideshow/All-in-1.jpg" alt="">

        <img src="image/slideshow/ECO.jpg" alt="">

        <img src="image/slideshow/Fairy-Tale.jpg" alt="">

        <img src="image/slideshow/Heritage.jpg" alt="" />

        <img src="image/slideshow/honey.jpg" />

        <img src="image/slideshow/incense.jpg" />

        <img src="image/slideshow/Moods.jpg" />

        <img src="image/slideshow/Morning.jpg" />

        <img src="image/slideshow/Natya.jpg" />

        <img src="image/slideshow/Prestige.jpg" />

        <img src="image/slideshow/Sandalum.jpg" />

        <img src="image/slideshow/Three.jpg" />

        <img src="image/slideshow/wood.jpg" />


    </div>

    <div id="caption1" class="nivo-html-caption">
        <strong>New Project</strong> <span></span> <em>Some description   
        here</em>.
    </div>

    <div id="caption3" class="nivo-html-caption">
        <strong>Image 3</strong> <span></span> <em>Some description 
       here</em>.
    </div>

  </div>
     <br /><br />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery.nivo.slider.js"></script>
   <script>
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#slider').nivoSlider({
        effect: 'random',
        directionNavHide: false,
        pauseOnHover: true,
        captionOpacity: 1,
        prevText: '<',
        nextText: '>'
    });
    });
    </script>
```

I had used following code but it takes me to new page instead of loading the page in the "#main" div.

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   $('#link1').on('click', 'a', function(e){ //step 1
   e.preventDefault(); //prevent default action, step2
   var url = url("content/home.html"); //get the url, step 2

   $.ajax({ //step 3
   type: 'GET',
     url: url,
  //your other options
   success: function(data){ //on success
    $('#main').html(data); //update your div, step 4
     }
     });
    });
  });
```

Previously I had tried following code, which works but the Jquery script doesn't work with it

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $(document).on('click', '#link1', function (e) {
      $('#main').load("content/home.html");
      e.preventDefault();
     });
    });
```

Here is what I am getting

http://i40.tinypic.com/2nsncs4.jpg

Here is what I Want

http://i42.tinypic.com/tapoaa.jpg

Please help me out i am struck ed.
Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you be more specific? what is not working properly? any console errors?

Comment: You need the [jQuery load() function](http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments) to load other pages into your current one

Comment: You are using `$(window).load()` what do you want to achieve with that?

Comment: To load html content use $('#main').load("content/home.html");

Comment: `var url = url("content/home.html");` <- what's going on there?

Comment: @Sergio Thank you for your response, specifically i what to change my page div content having id #main dynamically using AJAX / Jquery I had tried it with load() method but with that my image slider script ("jquery.nivo.slider.js") doesn't worked but normally it works in static index.html page. So i searched for another method and i got the above one. But it takes me to new page instead of displaying the page in the #main div.

Comment: @Musa I had just copied pasted from some other source, I think it converts the href attrib to url object.

Answer (score 0):

Things where you are wrong:

- The way you are Binding event on `#link1`, this should be `$(container).on(event, target, function)`
- url should be string, I don't understand what is `url("url.html")`

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '#link1', function (e) {
        var url = "content/home.html";

        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type : 'GET',
            url : url,
            //your other options
            success : function (data) {
                $('#main').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

***Or instead on `$.ajax()`, you can simply do `$.load()` like:***

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '#link1', function (e) {
        $('#main').load("content/home.html");
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Ashish for your response. The first solution is not working. But the second solution you had given is already tried by me earlier. I had a problem with it. By using it I get my page div section filled with content but the script of slider does not work.

Comment: Ok, try using the slider script when your content is loaded. I mean in the success function of the ajax.

Comment: OK,can you please show me how to do that since i am pretty much new to ajax. My script is in "script/jquery.nivo.slider.js" and another script itself in html page

         <script>
          $(window).load(function() {
          $('#slider').nivoSlider({
          effect: 'random',
          directionNavHide: false,
          pauseOnHover: true,
          captionOpacity: 1,
          prevText: '<',
          nextText: '>'
         });
});
   </script>

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the whole $.ajax request stuff you can use straight the .load method from query

```
$( "#main" ).load( "our external url" );
```

[jqyery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

However if you have a complete html page in your external url, the whole page will be loaded inside your #main element. This means duplicate html, body and etc. tags. I guess this is not the result you expect.

If you like to load only a particular part of the remote / external page, use a content selector inside the .load method

```
$( "#main" ).load( "ajax/test.html #container" );
```

So you will load only the content of the element with container id from the external page into your #main element.